# R (dplyr) - Summarizing a data frame using paste

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to summarize my data frame using a group_by condition (as I've seen before on the stackexchange), but for some reason the code keeps running into errors. (Note I use Impala to pull data but I wouldn't get why this would be the problem). The goal of this is simply to condense my table (grouping with the 3 conditions shown), and the 4th is merged together into one string (the inner join was tested separately and worked fine)

```
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(stringr)

merged_data <- inner_join(attribute_data_filtered,name_data_filtered, by = c('key' = 'assigned_key')) %>%
    arrange(key,attribute,name,login) %>%
    distinct(key,attribute,name,login, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(key,name,login) %>%
    summarise(new_col= paste(attribute, collapse = "_")) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(key,new_col,name,login) %>%
    collect()
```

The code keeps spitting out nonsense errors saying the parameter "collapse" cannot be used and should instead be replaced by str_flatten. And when I try using str_flatten it says that is also invalid. Any indications on what would be the problem?

Error Message:

```
Error in 'check_collapse()':
! 'collapse' not supported in DB translation of paste()'.
i.please use str_flatten() instead.
```

I've removed the summarise part and the code runs fine, but as soon as I put it in I encounter an error. I also tried using mutate (instead of summarise) for fun and it ran but didn't actually paste all the individual strings (not sure why)

Comment: Have you tried using `base::paste()`? Or, like the error says, tried using `str_flatten()`?

Comment: Error seems pretty clear, replace `paste` with `str_flatten`. Quick fix. Even the argument `collapse` has the same name.

Comment: Note that function availability depends on the backend.  For instance, `str_flatten()` is not (yet) available with SQLite but works with, for example, Postgres or duckdb. Seems it doesn't work with Impala.

Comment: If the join and distinct steps are already done, it might work to move your `collect()` step up above `group_by` so that the summarize is done downstream of your database. That might not be as fast as it could theoretically be done upstream, but it has the notable advantage that it would actually work.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento You’re exactly right the function comes up as unavailable when I replace

Comment: @JonSpring You're a live saver this worked like a charm. Is there an intuition behind this if I were to encounter something like this again?

Comment: `collect()` marks the transition from "translate this dplyr code into my database's syntax" to "use dplyr from here on out." So if some of the code can't be translated (at least currently) into your database syntax, extract the data and start using dplyr for that/those steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbplyr` translates dplyr syntax into your database's syntax. Some dplyr/tidyr/etc. functions/options are not available for some databases. So in general, if you have

```
database_table |>
  do_stuff_that_translates_fine() |>
  do_stuff_that_doesnt_translate() |>
  collect()
```

you can replace that with

```
database_table |>
  do_stuff_that_translates_fine() |>
  collect() |> 
  do_stuff_that_doesnt_translate()
```

so in this case I expect moving the `collect()` line above the `group_by` would avoid needing to translate the `paste(... collapse = "_")` or `str_flatten()` steps that aren't working.